Fixing Issues with Running xcodebuild in a Sandboxed macOS App
I have a problem where xcodebuild doesn’t run properly due to the macOS app sandbox restrictions. I’ve tried a few things to solve it by adjusting app permissions, but the issue persists. Here’s the approach I used:

Setting Up App Permissions:
I made sure the app has the right permissions to access files and perform network tasks. This was done by editing the app's entitlements file. The following settings were added to the entitlements file:
 <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
 <true/>
 <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
 <true/>
 <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
 <true/>
 <key>com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write</key>
 <true/>
 <key>com.apple.security.files.documents.read-write</key>
 <true/>
 <key>com.apple.security.files.desktop.read-write</key>
 <true/> </dict> </plist>


Running xcodebuild:
Next, I ran xcodebuild from my app using the Process class. Here’s the code that sets up the paths for the framework and archive, then runs the build command:



if let myFrameworkURL: URL = frameworkURL, let myOutputFolderURL: URL = outputFolderURL {
    let frameworkDirectoryPath: String = myFrameworkURL.deletingLastPathComponent().path
    let scheme: String = myFrameworkURL.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
    let archivePath: String = myOutputFolderURL
        .appendingPathComponent(scheme)
        .appendingPathExtension("xcarchive")
        .path

    let process = Process()
    process.currentDirectoryPath = frameworkDirectoryPath
    process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/xcodebuild")
    process.arguments = [
        "archive",
        "-scheme", scheme,
        "-configuration", "Release",
        "-destination", "platform=macOS,arch=x86_64",
        "-archivePath", archivePath,
        "SKIP_INSTALL=NO",
        "BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES"
    ]

    do {
        try process.run()
        process.waitUntilExit()
        if process.terminationStatus == 0 {
            print("Archive succeeded!")
        } else {
            print("Archive failed with status: \(process.terminationStatus)")
            if process.terminationStatus == 1 {
                print("Check if App Sandbox is restricting access to xcodebuild.")
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed to execute xcodebuild: \(error)")
    }
}



Allowing Full Disk Access:
Even after modifying the entitlements, I attempted to allow Full Disk Access for the app. This involves adding the app to the Full Disk Access list in System Preferences, but the issue persists.
Conclusion:
By adding the necessary permissions in the entitlements file and setting up the xcodebuild command, I tried to get the app to run smoothly. Despite providing full disk access, I am still facing challenges with running the xcodebuild process due to sandbox restrictions.

Error: "Check if App Sandbox is restricting access to xcodebuild."
